# Unwanted space between image and slider in flexbox. How to remove it?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

```css
#slider1 {
  height: 1px;
  width: 90px;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuQYf.png" alt="" />
  <input type="range" id="slider1" />
</div>
<p>See the space between the image and slider?</p>
```

How do I remove the unwanted space between image and slider? Seems like there is no padding or margin involved here, so my attempts failed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is created by the element itself before it gets the transform and the rotation won't remove that space.

So, before rotating the input do a `translateX(-50%)`: in case you need a better control of the position use a different value than 50%

```css
#slider1 {
  height: 1px;
  width: 90px;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(270deg);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuQYf.png" alt="" />
  <input type="range" id="slider1" />
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry I am late, just one question: does the order matter when writing the `transform` property? I think it does, I accidentally interchanged them and the result was unintended ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

you can change `padding: 0 11px;`

```css
#slider1 {
    writing-mode: bt-lr;
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
    width: 0px;
    height: 90px;
    padding: 0 2px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuQYf.png" alt="" />
  <input type="range" id="slider1" />
</div>
<p>See the space between the image and slider?</p>
```

Comment: Though this approach works, there is some problem with custom CSS styling. See my last question for details.